# Is there a way to connect to a bluetooth device by a django web app (so with python)?

Tags: python, django, bluetooth-lowenergy

I a personal project I was able to connect via Bluetooth to a device that measure body temperature with some python libraries.
I want to implement this code in a Django web app to collect data from these Bluetooth devices, is this possible?
Can you suggest me, if is it possible, how can I get this work in Django?

Thanks in advance,
Marco

Comment: django is python so you should be able to do the same thing.

Comment: it would list bluetooth devices that could be reached by the server(if you did it in django(which is just python)) ... at a guess you want to reach client side devices? if thats the case you would need javascript (assuming the type of device you want to connect to is one that works with browsers)

Comment: @JoranBeasley the goal is to read values from Ble devices like body temperature, heart rate probably, etc.

Comment: @crimson589 the point is that that connecting to a ble device by client side. Is it possible with python or only Javascript?

Comment: @MarkPT you can try making your app a PWA, this will give access to some hardware features https://whatpwacando.today/ , although I think it requires your site to be secure(https)

Comment: On the client side, I am only aware of this being done with [web bluetooth](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/) API in javascript